# Salesforce Lightnining unable to see full values in UI Picklist

Tags: lightning, picklist, bug, ui

In Salesforce Lightning Experience, whenever I have a 'Classic view' picklist, when I click on the picklist to choose a value, I am unable to view the select options:

[image]

If i minimize my browser window and maximize it, this corrects itself and the same picklist now shows the entire value.

I am the only one in my team that experiences this issue. We all use the same browser (google chrome).

I found the following issue in Salesforce ('In Review' & 'Unresolved'), however based on the description, I am not sure if this is the same bug.
  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYzWQAW

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour?
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Subscribe to that issue and wait until it is resolved or use Classic meanwhile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to have been caused by chrome extensions. I had various extensions installed that were designed for SF classic. I disabled all of them and this seems to have solved the problem.

I apologize if this was the incorrect forum to post this type of question.